# Render python object to HTML - simple types but nested - in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

### Convert Python object to HTML (table or frameset) to render in django

Any suggestions on how to iterate thru an arbitrary python object attributes and render to html? There wont be need to call any methods.
The object would contain: *String*, *integer*, *datetime*, *list* of these types, and other similar python objects (different class but still *String*, *integer*, *datetime*, *list*..). The nesting could be 5-6 levels deep.

I want to render to html (something like either table, or frameset, etc), and set class / id in html for future CSS ( not necessary to dive into css in this question). Here is a simplified, sample Python object:

```
name    : Mr sandman
addr    :
        street 1: 123 main st
        street 2: None
        city    : Los angeles
        state   : ca
        zip     : 90001

events :[
        date_of_birth : datetime(2013, 01, 01) ,
        date_of_grad  : None
        ]
is_married : False
has_children : None
awards:[
        (award:
            name   : bravery
            date   : datetime(2010,01,01)), 
        (award:
            name   : courage
            date   : None ),
        ]
```

Alternatively, rendering similar json to html would also be helpful.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do here, Do you want it as a table? or as a list? What to you mean "rendered to HTML"

Comment: Thx. I clarified. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest approach would be translate your python object to JSON first.
then use one of many json to html converter. 
EX:
https://github.com/bloopletech/json2html/tree/master

demo
http://json.bloople.net/#_output

because your python object include datetime type, the json decoder need to be extended first.

```
import json
def extend_json(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, date):
        return str(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, datetime):
        return obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return float(obj)

data = json.dumps(obj, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=extend_json)
```